# How to redirect to a specific sub domain in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've created a middleware to redirect a user to a specific sub-domain based on the user's account type.

I want to prevent a basic user from accessing the admin sub-domain and be redirected back to their home page.

I've tried this:

```
if($user->isAccountType('basic')){
    return Redirect::to('basic.myapp.app/home');
}

return $next($request);
```

But all that happens is the laravel will try to redirect to admin.myapp.app/basic.myapp.app/home.

Is it possible to redirect them to basic.myapp.app/home?

Comment: Have you tried with the absolute path.. ? ie., your full subdomain with `http://` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend the protocol:

```
if($user->isAccountType('basic')){
    return Redirect::to('http://basic.myapp.app/home');
}

return $next($request);
```

Rather than hard coding your subdomains into your middlewares or controllers, I'd place them inside a config so they stay easily configurable.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Will put it in the config soon. Just needed to get something up and running quickly for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this already?

```
if($user->isAccountType('basic')){
    return Redirect::to('/basic.myapp.app/home');
}

return $next($request);
```

Using a named route is also a good option

Comment: This will also redirect to `admin.myapp.app/basic.myapp.app/home`

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect using the named route, this will work perfectly:

```
return redirect()->route('route.name');
```

To get the route names, use the following artisan command:

```
php artisan route:list
```